# Django multi-table inheritance - make sure only one child exists (CheckConstraint)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multi-table-inheritance, django-constraints

How can I make sure that a parent object has only one child/type?

```
class Property(...):
    class Meta:
        abstract = False

class Flat(Property):
    pass

class House(Property):
    pass 

class Land(Property):
    pass
```

I want every property object to have none or at most one child. It can be either `flat`, `house` or `land` (or `null`).

Is it possible to create a DB constraint for this?

My idea was to create a constraint that checks:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(check=Q(Q(flat__isnull=True) & Q(house__isnull=True)) 
                                     | 
                                     Q(Q(flat__isnull=True) & Q(land__isnull=True)) 
                                     |
                                     Q(Q(house__isnull=True) & Q(land__isnull=True)), 
                                name="constraint")]
```

But apparently, there are no such fields on a DB level (you can get `flat` by `property.flat` getter in Django but not in DB)

## Edit:

```
properties.Property: (models.E012) 'constraints' refers to the nonexistent field 'flat'.
```

Comment: You can't create a database constraint for this, since a `CHECK` constraint only spans a *row* for *one* table, so you can not make JOINs on other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But apparently, there are no such fields on a DB level (you can get flat by `property.flat` getter in Django but not in DB)

That is correct: Django adds a property to the `Property` model to lazily load the related `Flat` object and will make a query for that, but there is no database field named `flat`: this is just a query in reverse where Django basically queries with:

```
SELECT * FROM app_name_flat WHERE property_ptr=pk
```

with *`pk`* the primary key of the `property` object. It this makes a query.

A [**`CHECK`** constraint <sup>[w3-schools]</sup>](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) spans only over a *row*: it can not look on other rows nor can it look at other tables. It thus can not restrict other tables, and therefore is limited. It can for example prevent one column to have a certain value based on a value for another column in the same row (record), but that is how far a `CHECK` constraint normally looks.